# Is my matrix operation correct?

Tags: matrices

I am converting a matrix into row-echelon form.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 2 & -1 & 6\\
   3 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
   2 & -1 & 2 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 2 & -1 & 6\\
   3-3 & 8-6 & 9+3 & 10-18\\
   2 & -1 & 2 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 2 & -1 & 6\\
   0 & 2 & 12 & -8\\
   2 & -1 & 2 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 2 & -1 & 6\\
   0 & 1 & 6 & -4\\
   0 & -5 & 4 & 10\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 2 & -1 & 6\\
   0 & 1 & 6 & -4\\
   0 & -5 & 4 & 10\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 2 & -1 & 6\\
   0 & 1 & 6 & -4\\
   0 & -2 & 8/5 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 2 & -1 & 6\\
   0 & 1 & 6 & -4\\
   0 & 0 & 18 & -5\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: There's an error in the third step. The element in the third row, fourth column should be -10

Comment: @GoodDeeds,   why? Couldn't understand.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but what you have done is that you have multiplied the first row by $-2$ and added the result to the third row. In the fourth column, the result will be $-2\times6+2=-10$.

Comment: @GoodDeeds. no. I have multiplied the 1st row by 3 and then subtracted 2nd row from that. 3rd row is untouched up to 3rd step.

Comment: @anonymous That's exactly the step I am talking about.

Comment: [This link](http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi) contains my answer plus the steps needed to arrive at that answer. Hope this helps.